# proof: $u \in L^q$ for all $q < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, sobolev-spaces

I want to show that $u(x)= \log \frac{1}{|x|}$ and $v(x)= \log \log \frac{1}{|x|}$ are in $L^q(\Omega)$ for all $1 \leq q < \infty$ for $\Omega = B_1(0) \subset \mathbb R^n$, $\Omega = B_{1/e}(0) \subset \mathbb R^n$ respectively.

(I posted the question yesterday, and I think I figured how it works.)

$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}$

---

1. For $r =1$ and $r =0$ we have $\log r = 0$ and $r^{n-1}= 0$ respectively, so we can integrate by parts after changing to polar coordinates. Then

   $$\int_\Omega |u|^q \, \dd x = C \int_0^1 |\log r|^q \, r^{n-1} \, \dd r = - C \int_0^1 |\log r|^{q-1} \, \frac{r^{n-1}}{n} \, \dd r \\ = \cdots = (-1)^{[q]} \, C \int_0^1 |\log r|^{q - [q]} \, \frac{r^{n-1}}{n^{[q]}} \, \dd r $$ where $[\cdot]$ is the floor function

   Let $\alpha =: q - [q] \in [0,1]$ hence we can split and estimate

   $$ C \int_0^\frac{1}{e} \underbrace{|\log r|^\alpha}_{\leq |\log r|} \, \, r^{n-1} \, \dd r \leq C \int_0^\frac{1}{e} r^{n-1} \, \dd r < \infty $$

   $$ C \int_\frac{1}{e}^1 \underbrace{|\log r|^\alpha}_{\leq |\log r|^0} \, \, r^{n-1} \, \dd r \leq C \int_\frac{1}{e}^1  r^{n-1} \, \dd r < \infty $$

   Hence $\log \frac{1}{|x|} \in \bigcap_{1 \leq q < \infty} L^q(\Omega)$

$\,$

2. essentially the same as above, change to polar coordinates, then again we are able to integrate by parts, after a substitution:

   $$\int_\Omega |v|^q \, \dd x = C \int_0^\frac{1}{e} \Big(\log \log \frac{1}{r}\Big)^q \, r^{n-1} \, \dd r = C \int_1^\infty ( \log x )^q \, e^{-nx} \, \dd x \\ 
   = - C \int_1^\infty (\log x)^{q-1} \, \frac{e^{-nx}}{-nx} \, \dd x = \cdots = (-1)^{[q]} C \int_1^\infty (\log x)^{q-[q]} \, \frac{e^{-nx}}{(-nx)^{[q]}} \, \dd x$$

and $\alpha = q- [q] \in [0,1]$ hence $(\log x)^\alpha \leq \log x$ for $x \in [1,\infty)$ and the integral converges

Comment: no one? good / bad / too boring?

Comment: Assuming your $C$ is different at each equality, I guess your work is OK but quite tedious after changing to polar coordinates. Why not just using the fact that $\forall \alpha > 0 ,  \ln(r) = o\left(r^{-\alpha}\right)$ near $0$ for the first function and the fact that $\forall \alpha > 0 ,  \ln(r) = o\left(r^{\alpha}\right)$ near $+\infty$ for the second one ?

Comment: because i didn't know that ;-) thanks!

Comment: @yultan, following your advice, do I understand you correctly: for $0 < n - 1 - \alpha$ and a suitable $\varepsilon >0$ we have  $$\int_0^1 |\log r|^q \, r^{n-1} \, \mathrm d r = \int_0^\varepsilon o(r^{-\alpha}) \, r^{n-1} \, \mathrm d r + \int_\varepsilon^1 |\log r|^q \, r^{n-1} \, \mathrm d r \leq C$$

Comment: That is the idea. But be careful, the condition on $\alpha$ is $-q\alpha + n - 1 > 0 $. You could also detail even less. Since $|\log r |^q r^{n-1} $ in continuous on $(0,1]$, the only issue is near $0$, which is solved by comparison test using our $r^{-q\alpha + n - 1}$ upper bound.

Comment: first i thought this makes sense, but how is this any different than what i wrote down above?

Comment: Well first, what you wrote above needs the little correction $\left(o(r^{-\alpha})\right)^q$. Apart from that, yes it is the same argument, but it doesn't require to use explicitely an $\epsilon$ and doesn't require to cut the integral in two parts.

Comment: agreed! but how do i show that $|\log r| \leq r^{-\alpha}$ for any $\alpha >0$? this should be fairly simple, yet im unable to come up with the right idea

Comment: Well if you know the fact that $\lim_{r \to 0 } r \log r = 0 $ then for all $\alpha > 0 $, $ \lim_{r \to 0 }  r^{\alpha} \log  r^{\alpha}  = 0 = \lim_{r \to 0 }   \alpha r^{\alpha} \log  r  $. So if $r$ is close enough to zero, it exists $C_{\alpha} > 0 $ such that $|\log r | < C_{\alpha}  r^{-\alpha}$

Comment: that i know, thats what i did above; however i thought you were suggesting to bound $|\log r|^q$ on the whole interval $(0,1)$ by $r^{-\alpha}$, and that i couldnt manage to do $$\,$$
i can show this for $\alpha \geq 0$ and for generic $\alpha >0$ i can show that $$|\log r| \leq \frac{r^{-\alpha}}{\alpha}$$

Comment: hahaha, nvm its wrong otherwise, i think i just misunderstood your suggestions ;-)

#timewellspent